# CBC-MAC key can be added to ciphertext?

Tags: aes, cbc, authenticated-encryption, integrity, cbc-mac

I use AES both CBC and CBC-MAC to encrypt some stuff. I generate one key for CBC and one different key for CBC-MAC.

1. Does the second key (for CBC-MAC) need to be secret?
2. How to join such key with the ciphertext? By contatenating it at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the sound of your questions, it almost appears that you have some confusion between the CBC-MAC key and the CBC-MAC tag.

The CBC-MAC algorithm takes the message (in this case, most likely the ciphertext) and a secret key; it outputs a tag (which can be public).  The security property of CBC-MAC is that someone who does not know the key cannot generate a valid message, tag pair, even if he sees a huge number of valid message, tag pairs (of course, he is not allowed to suggest a message, tag pair that he has been given).  Actually, it works even if he is allowed to specify the messages.

The idea is that if the receiver (Bob) gets a message and tag pair that validates, that means that the sender (Alice) must have generated it.  After all, only someone who knows the key is able to generate such a pair, and the only two are Alice and Bob (and Bob knows he'll never generate such a pair, so Alice must have sent it).

With that in mind, your questions:

> Does the second key (for CBC-MAC) need to be secret?

Absolutely; if the attacker is given that key, then all security bets are off.  He can easily generate a valid MAC tag for any message he picks.

> How to join such key with the ciphertext? By concatenating it at the end?

No, you don't send out the key with the ciphertext; it needs to be secret.  On the other hand, you can send the *tag* with the ciphertext; concatenating the tag at the end is one common approach.

Comment: Thanks. So I need to send to the sender - in private - both key for CBC and key for CBC-MAC ?

Comment: @Kingland: yes (or somehow otherwise have both sides arrive at the same secret keys)

Answer (score 1):

As additional detail, while the two keys need to be distinct and secret, you can derive the CBC-MAC key and the CBC encryption key from the same master key.

Generate a random master key, then use any key derivation algorithm with two different salts to derive the authentication and encryption keys. For example, $K(m, \text{'auth'})$ and $K(m, \text{'enc'})$ where $K$ is the key derivation function, like [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869).

That way you do not need to share any more keys than with unauthenticated encryption.